# How reindex_like function works with method "ffill" & "bfill"?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframe of shape (6,3) & (2,3). Now I want to reindex second dataframe like first dataframe and also fill na values with either ffill method or bfill method. my code is as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,3),columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,3),columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3'])
df2 = df2.reindex_like(df1,method='ffill')
```

But this code is not working well as I am getting following result:

```
    Col1      Col2      Col3
0  0.578282 -0.199872  0.468505
1  1.086811 -0.707933 -0.924984
2       NaN       NaN       NaN
3       NaN       NaN       NaN
4       NaN       NaN       NaN
5       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Any suggestion would be great

Comment: this works fine in mi laptop

Comment: @ansev this code is not working in my pc

Comment: What version are you using of pandas?

Comment: check df1.index and df2.index...
I think it's because the indexes are different

Comment: @ansev version is 0.23.4

Comment: I use 0.25.1..
it must be this....although it is very rare

Comment: @ansev may be bcoz of version problem it is not working

Comment: why don't you upgrade to pandas 0.25.1?